# How to remember last value of search?

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar, searchview

I use android SearchView which is in action bar. I have some ListView on which I search. I want to after I entered some search text this text remain in search bar, and I can  delete this text to  get my initial list. I saw applications which work like this. Please help me and also please tell me good tutorials for dynamic search while typing and for searchview callbacks.